# Connecting a linear potentiometer to an Arduino

Tags: arduino, potentiometer

How can I go about connecting a linear potentiometer to an Arduino?

[image]

[image: images of linear potentiometer]

Comment: you can connect anything to anything, but how you do that depends on what you use exactly ("Arduino" is just a product family, there's very many different arduinos, linear potentiometer says nothing about the pinout of that) and, most importantly, for which purpose.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a link to the datasheet (not an Amazon or Ali-what's-it page) for the potentiometer.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add. I dont have the datasheet. I am not really sure what I am working with

Comment: You want to read the voltage?  I mean for ADC?

Comment: Sadat Rafi. yes thats what I want to do

Comment: "how I can go about connecting a liner potentiometer to arduino" - Same way you would connect a rotary potentiometer. The physical shape doesn't matter.

Comment: You can determine which wire goes to which terminal of the pot using an ohmmeter.

Comment: how do you know it's a potentiometer, then?

Comment: I've never seen a potentiometer like this. Where does this comes from? It looks like an antenna with the wrong cable attached.

Comment: In order that someone can answer your question, please tell us WHAT do you want to do with the arduino and the potentiometer. The devices on this photo don't seem a potentiometer. One is a computer keyboard and the other seems to be an antenna.

Answer (score 0):

Pot is simple to connect. There are 3 terminals - top voltage (usually your Vcc), bottom voltage (usually ground) and middle terminal that outputs analog voltage you want.

Potentiometer is basically a voltage divider, where you can change the proportion of upper and lower resistor. Read about voltage dividers if you're not familiar. It's really-really easy.

What will happen, if you flip it around? What if you connect pin 1 to GND and pin 3 to Vcc? It will still work just fine, it's symmetric.

How do you know what terminal is what?

If it doesn't come with pot, you can measure resistance between every pair of wires on the pot. If you have some round number that doesn't change with pot turning, you're measuring between terminals 1 and 3. Connect any of them (1 or 3) to Vcc, the other (3 or 1) to GND, and the last unconnected lead will be pin 2 analog voltage.

[image]

Vin is your 5V, Vout goes to analog input pin of your Arduino. You can turn it around as much as you want, you'll never burn anything here.

Have fun with it :)

Comment: don't subestimate a newbie's ability to burn things. Let's say that the pot has a low value, let's say that the pot is 47 ohms...

Comment: fair point, I just assumed it's some common 10k/50k/100k pot, should have indicated that

Comment: You can edit your answer to include a mention that, in order of not burn anything, the pot has to be (what minimum? 470 ohms, 1K?) of some value or higher, and explain the reason for this limit.